# PDF content is not enough to reconstruct the PDF?

Tags: pdf, binaryfiles

I open a pdf file "test.pdf" with Vim and copy its content to another text buffer that I save as "copy.pdf". I don't understand why "copy.pdf" is different, can be opened as a pdf (the title shows) but the page is empty.

The same happens when I read the file in Javascript with `FileReader.readAsBinaryString` and rewrite it to disk, so it is not related to how I copy in Vim.

Even more strange, the Finder says that the copy is actually 30KB bigger.

Where are the hidden bytes?

Comment: Every process where the result differs from the original is not creating an identical copy. Thus, both your processes (using vim, using JavaScript) are not appropriate for copying binaries. The reasons may differ. Vim is a text editor, thus it has certain assumptions on the nature of the data it processes. PDF is a binary format and, therefore, most likely does not fulfil these assumptions. So vim may damage the data in the process. In your JavaScript process both reading and writing must respect the binary nature of the data. You show only one side of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when I see this sort of behavior and resulting blank pages, it is the result of using a program or process that is treating the binary information of a PDF as text in some form or another - for example, doing CR/LF conversion, tab to space conversion or interpreting the data as UTF-8 instead of binary. Doing any sort of transformation will ruin the binary streams within a PDF and will cause the offset bytes in the cross-reference table to become incorrect, causing the PDF to be unreadable.
Perhaps your process of writing back to disk doing CR/LF conversion or otherwise treating your binary blob as non-binary?